# Using sub-query to count specific rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I am using for a report. Each line is a row of data containing a medical history, the `client_id` is repeated for each medical history.

I'm grouping by `client_id` and summing their conditions but I want to use a sub-query to find any conditions that are above a preset score. My current query is giving me the total for the whole table, not just the specific `client_id`.

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Here my query:

```
select 
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, taken_on), 0), 
    client_id, 
    count(hscore), 
    sum(hscore),
    (select count(hscore) 
            from amexmedscreen 
            where hscore >= '3.5') 
    from amexmedscreen 
    group by taken_on, client_id`
```

Comment: So you want count(hscore) for each client_id and taken_on, but in that last value you only want to count hscores >= 3.5?

Answer (score 6):

It should be sufficient to use `CASE` to get `1` for relevant rows, and `sum` those:

```
select 
    ...
    sum(hscore),
    sum(CASE WHEN hscore >= 3.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
group by taken_on, client_id`
```

Comment: I think he wants the sum to be relative to the client aggregation only, not client and taken_on

Comment: @WinstonSmith: You might be right, but it's difficult to tell. The OP only mentions `grouping by clientid` even though the query groups by `client_id` **and** `taken_on`. In the other case i think I'd first do that select, only grouping by `client_id`, and nest it in another query grouping by `taken_on` and `client_id`.

Comment: `END` is knocking on the door and yelling 'Let me in!', but no one seems to hear...

Comment: @AndriyM: Thanks for noticing that poor thing, fixed ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery is a separate query. It's not constrained by what's going on in the main query. You need to tell it to do the count only for the client_id of the current record in the outer query. You'll be referring to the same table twice in two different queries, so you'll have to use a different alias for each one.

Something like this should work:

```
select DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, taken_on), 0), 
     client_id, 
     count(hscore), 
     sum(hscore),
     (select count(hscore) 
      from amexmedscreen subq 
      where 
          hscore >= '3.5' 
          and subq.client_id = outerq.client_id )
from amexmedscreen outerq
group by taken_on, client_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, taken_on), 0), 
client_id, 
count(hscore), 
sum(hscore),
tb1.COUNT_HSCORE
from amexmedscreen 
INNER JOIN 
(select client_id, count(hscore) as COUNT_HSCORE
 from amexmedscreen 
 where hscore >= '3.5' 
 group by client_ID) as tb1
ON tb1.client_id = client id
group by taken_on, client_id,tb1.COUNT_HSCORE
```